# Spring Integration Aggregator Issue or MisConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am using Spring Integration to manage some scheduled tasks, and one of them i choose to use a `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` with an aggregator at the end to collect the tasks result as follows. Is it anything missing for the message  arrive on on last channel "*responseHttpChannel*"? Its not the first time that i use Spring Integration neither the http gateway. but on this scenario i could never put an ***aggregator*** to work. Inside this request-response the message do a some other tasks. if at least the timeout works for me it already a victory.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableIntegrationGraphController(path = "/integration", allowedOrigins="*")
public class SysmatIntegrationConfiguration {

    private static final String MESSAGE_ORIGIN = "MESSAGE_ORIGIN";
    
    @Autowired
    IndexSchedulerService<IndexScheduler<?>> indexSchedulerService;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    ListaTarefaItemHistorySplitter tarefaItemHistorySplitter; 

    @Autowired
    ListTarefaItemSpliter tarefaItemSplitter;

    @Autowired
    SelecionadorItem selecionadorItem;

    @Autowired  
    TarefaItemHistoryLog tarefaItemHistoryLog;

    @Autowired
    TarefaIndexarItemMaster tarefaIndexarItemMaster;
    
    public SysmatIntegrationConfiguration() {
    }

    @Bean
    public HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy headerAttributeCorrelationStrategy() {
        return new HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID);
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value="expressionParser")
    ExpressionParser expressionParser() {
        return new SpelExpressionParser();
    }


    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value="indexTarefaTemplate")
    public MessagingTemplate indexTarefaTemplate(@Autowired @Qualifier("tarefaControllerChannel") MessageChannel indexChannel) { 
        return new MessagingTemplate(indexChannel);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier(value="jobMessageTemplate")
    public MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate(@Autowired @Qualifier("indexChannel") MessageChannel indexChannel) { 
        MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate(indexChannel);
        return  messagingTemplate;
    }
    //schedulerMessageTemplate

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier(value="schedulerMessageTemplate")
    public MessagingTemplate schedulerMessageTemplate(@Autowired @Qualifier("tarefaIndexSchedulerChannel") MessageChannel tarefaIndexSchedulerChannel) { 
        MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate(tarefaIndexSchedulerChannel);
        return  messagingTemplate;
    }
    
    @Bean(name="threadFactory")
    @Qualifier("threadFactory")
    public ThreadFactory highPriorityThreadFactory() { 
        return constructThread(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY , false); 
    }
    
    @Bean(name="normalPriorityThreadFactory")
    @Qualifier("normalPriorityThreadFactory")
    public ThreadFactory normalPriorityThreadFactory() { 
        return constructThread(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY , false); 
    }

    private ThreadFactory constructThread(final int priority , final Boolean daemon) { 
        return new ThreadFactory() { 
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                Thread t = new Thread(r);
                t.setDaemon(Optional.ofNullable(daemon).orElse(false));
                t.setPriority(priority);
                return t;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean(name="threadPoolExecutor")
    @Qualifier(value="threadPoolExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadFactory") ThreadFactory threadFactory) { 
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor tpe =  new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        tpe.setCorePoolSize(100);
        tpe.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        tpe.setThreadFactory(threadFactory);
        return tpe;
    }
    
    @Bean(name="taskScheduler")
    @Qualifier(value="taskScheduler")
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler(@Autowired @Qualifier("normalPriorityThreadFactory") ThreadFactory threadFactory) { 
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler tpe =  new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        tpe.setThreadNamePrefix("IntegrationPoolTaskScheduler");
        tpe.setThreadFactory(threadFactory);
        tpe.setPoolSize(20);
        return tpe;
    }
    
    @Bean(name="threadPoolTaskScheduler")
    @Qualifier(value="threadPoolTaskScheduler")
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler(@Autowired @Qualifier("normalPriorityThreadFactory") ThreadFactory threadFactory) { 
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler tpe =  new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        tpe.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        tpe.setThreadFactory(threadFactory);
        tpe.setPoolSize(20);
        return tpe;
    }

    @Bean 
    @Qualifier(value="myTaskRegistar")
    public ScheduledTaskRegistrar myTaskRegistar(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadPoolTaskScheduler")TaskScheduler taskScheduler) {
        ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar = new ScheduledTaskRegistrar();
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
        return scheduledTaskRegistrar;
    }
    
    
    @Primary
    @Bean("httpMessageConverters")
    public List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters(){ 
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(new ObjectMapper()));
        converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        return converters;
    }

    @Bean(name="defaultHttpHeaderMapper")
    @Qualifier(value="defaultHttpHeaderMapper")
    public DefaultHttpHeaderMapper defaultHeaderMapper() { 
        DefaultHttpHeaderMapper mapper = new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper();
        mapper.setInboundHeaderNames(new String[] {"*"});
        mapper.setOutboundHeaderNames(new String[] {"*"});
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("indexChannel")
    public MessageChannel indexChannel(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadPoolExecutor")ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor) {
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = MessageChannels
                .publishSubscribe("indexChannel" , threadPoolExecutor)
                .get();
        return psc;
    }

    @Bean(name="tarefaIndexChannel")
    @Qualifier(value="tarefaIndexChannel")
    public MessageChannel tarefaIndexChannel(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadPoolExecutor")ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor) { 
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = MessageChannels
                .publishSubscribe("tarefaIndexChannel" , threadPoolExecutor)
                .get();
        return psc;
    }
    
    @Bean(name="tarefaIndexSchedulerChannel")
    @Qualifier(value="tarefaIndexSchedulerChannel")
    public MessageChannel tarefaIndexSchedulerChannel(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadPoolExecutor")ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor) { 
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = MessageChannels
                .publishSubscribe("tarefaIndexSchedulerChannel" , threadPoolExecutor)
                .get();
        return psc;
    }

    @Bean(name="tarefaItemMasterIndexChannel")
    @Qualifier(value="tarefaItemMasterIndexChannel")
    public MessageChannel tarefaItemMasterIndexChannel(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadPoolExecutor")ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor) { 
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = MessageChannels
                .publishSubscribe("tarefaIndexChannel" , threadPoolExecutor)
                .get();
        return psc;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("logginChannel")
    public DirectChannel loggingChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name="tarefaPartitionChannel")
    @Qualifier(value="tarefaPartitionChannel")
    public MessageChannel tarefaPartitionChannel(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadPoolExecutor")ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor) { 
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = MessageChannels
                .publishSubscribe("tarefaPartitionChannel" , threadPoolExecutor)
                .get();
        return psc;
    }


    @Bean(name="tarefaControllerChannel")
    @Qualifier(value="tarefaControllerChannel")
    public MessageChannel tarefaControllerChannel() { 
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    
    @Bean(name="tarefaHttpIntegrationChannel")
    @Qualifier(value="tarefaHttpIntegrationChannel")
    public MessageChannel tarefaHttpIntegrationChannel(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadPoolExecutor")ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor) { 
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = MessageChannels
                .publishSubscribe("tarefaHttpIntegrationChannel" , threadPoolExecutor)
                .get();
        return psc; 
    }
    
    @Bean(name="tarefaHttpIndexIntegrationChannel")
    @Qualifier(value="tarefaHttpIndexIntegrationChannel")
    public MessageChannel tarefaHttpIndexIntegrationChannel(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadPoolExecutor")ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor) { 
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = MessageChannels
                .publishSubscribe("tarefaHttpIndexIntegrationChannel" , threadPoolExecutor)
                .get();
        return psc; 
    }


    @Bean(name="sumarizaTarefaChannel")
    @Qualifier(value="sumarizaTarefaChannel")
    public MessageChannel sumarizaTarefaChannel(@Autowired @Qualifier("threadPoolExecutor")ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolExecutor) { 
        PublishSubscribeChannel psc = MessageChannels
                .publishSubscribe("sumarizaTarefaChannel" , threadPoolExecutor)
                .get();
        return psc;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow loggingFlow(@Autowired 
            @Qualifier("loggingChannel") MessageChannel logChannel) {
        return  IntegrationFlows
                .from(logChannel)
                .handle(m -> logMessage(m))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow indexPrepareFlow(@Autowired  @Qualifier("indexChannel") MessageChannel indexChannel , 
            @Autowired  @Qualifier("tarefaIndexChannel") MessageChannel tarefaIndexChannel) {
        return  IntegrationFlows
                .from(indexChannel)
                .transform(selecionadorItem)
                .channel("tarefaPartitionChannel").get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow itemRouteToPartition(@Autowired HttpRequestHandler httpRequestHandler) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("tarefaHttpIntegrationChannel")
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(MESSAGE_ORIGIN, "HTTP"))
                .handle(httpRequestHandler)
                .get();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow indexRouteToPartition() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("tarefaControllerChannel")
                .channel("tarefaPartitionChannel").get();

    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow indexSchedulerRouteToPartition(@Autowired TarefaIndexScheduler tarefaIndexScheduler) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("tarefaIndexSchedulerChannel")
                .transform(tarefaIndexScheduler)
                .channel("tarefaPartitionChannel").get();

    }
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow indexSplitHistory(@Autowired IndexTaskMonitor indexTaskMonitor) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("tarefaPartitionChannel")
                .wireTap(flow -> flow.handle(m->indexTaskMonitor.processIndexRequest(m.getPayload())))
                .split(tarefaItemHistorySplitter)
                .channel("tarefaIndexChannel").get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow indexFlow(@Autowired  @Qualifier("tarefaIndexChannel") MessageChannel tarefaIndexChannel
            ,@Autowired @Qualifier("tarefaItemMasterIndexChannel") MessageChannel indexMasterChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(tarefaIndexChannel)
                .routeToRecipients(route ->
                                    route.recipientFlow(subFlow -> 
                                                        subFlow.transform(tarefaItemHistoryLog)
                                                        .split(tarefaItemSplitter)
                                                        .channel(indexMasterChannel)))
                .get();
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow indexItemMasterFlow(@Autowired @Qualifier("tarefaItemMasterIndexChannel") MessageChannel indexMasterChannel,
            @Autowired @Qualifier("loggingChannel") MessageChannel logChannel ,
            @Autowired JmsMessageSender jmsSender) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(indexMasterChannel)
                .transform(tarefaIndexarItemMaster)
                .channel(logChannel)
                .handle(m -> jmsSender.send(m.getPayload()))
                .get();
    }   
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sumarizaIndexItemFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("sumarizaTarefaChannel")
                .wireTap(subflow -> 
                                                            subflow
                                                            .filter(new GenericSelector<Message<?>>() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public boolean accept(Message<?> source) {
                                                                    return Optional
                                                                                    .ofNullable(source.getHeaders().get(MESSAGE_ORIGIN))
                                                                                    .map(h -> h.equals("HTTP")).orElse(false);
                                                                }
                                                            })
                                                            .channel(c -> c.direct("prehttpChannel")))
                .wireTap(subflow ->
                                                                    subflow
                                                                    .filter(new GenericSelector<Message<?>>() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public boolean accept(Message<?> source) {
                                                                            return Optional
                                                                                            .ofNullable(source.getHeaders().get(MESSAGE_ORIGIN))
                                                                                            .map(h -> h.equals("SCHEDULER")).orElse(false);
                                                                        }
                                                                    })
                                                                    .channel(c -> c.direct("schedulerReplyChannel")))
                .get();

    }   
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpSchedulerRequestResponse() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("schedulerReplyChannel")
                .channel("loggingChannel")
                .get();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpResponse() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("prehttpChannel")
                .channel("responseHttpChannel")
                .channel("loggingChannel")
                .get();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CrossOrigin crossOrigin() {
        CrossOrigin co = new CrossOrigin();
        co.setOrigin("*");
        co.setMethod(RequestMethod.GET , RequestMethod.POST);
        return co;
    }
    
    @Bean(name="itemRequestMapping")
    @Qualifier(value="itemRequestMapping")
    public RequestMapping itemRequestMapping() { 
        RequestMapping mapping = new RequestMapping();
        mapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.GET , HttpMethod.POST);
        mapping.setConsumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        mapping.setProduces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        mapping.setPathPatterns("/int_sysmat/{id}");
        return mapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpRequestGateway
    (@Autowired @Qualifier("tarefaHttpIntegrationChannel") 
    MessageChannel tarefaHttpIntegrationChannel , 
    @Autowired @Qualifier("responseHttpChannel") MessageChannel responseHttpChannel,
    @Autowired @Qualifier("expressionParser") ExpressionParser parser,
    @Autowired @Qualifier("itemRequestMapping") RequestMapping requestMapping,
    @Autowired CrossOrigin crossOrigin, 
    @Autowired List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters) {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway g = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway();
        g.setRequestChannel(tarefaHttpIntegrationChannel);
        g.setReplyChannel(responseHttpChannel);
        g.setPayloadExpression(parser.parseExpression("#pathVariables.id"));
        g.setRequestMapping(requestMapping);
        g.setCrossOrigin(crossOrigin);
        g.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverters);
        g.setReplyTimeout(180000);
        return g;
    }
    
    @Bean(name="indexIntegrationRepresentationRequestMapping")
    @Qualifier(value="indexIntegrationRepresentationRequestMapping")
    public RequestMapping indexRepresentationRequestMapping() { 
        RequestMapping mapping = new RequestMapping();
        mapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.GET , HttpMethod.POST);
        mapping.setConsumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        mapping.setProduces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        mapping.setPathPatterns("/sysmat_index_integration");
        return mapping;
    }

    
    @Bean("httpSysmatIntegrationRequestGateway")
    @Qualifier(value="httpSysmatIntegrationRequestGateway")
    public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpSysmatIntegrationRequestGateway
    (@Autowired @Qualifier("tarefaHttpIndexIntegrationChannel") MessageChannel tarefaHttpIndexIntegrationChannel , 
    @Autowired @Qualifier("expressionParser") ExpressionParser parser,
    @Autowired @Qualifier("indexIntegrationRepresentationRequestMapping") RequestMapping requestMapping,
    @Autowired CrossOrigin crossOrigin, 
    @Autowired List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters , 
    @Autowired @Qualifier("responseHttpChannel")  MessageChannel httpResponseChannel) {
        HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway g = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway();
        g.setRequestChannel(tarefaHttpIndexIntegrationChannel);
        g.setReplyChannel(httpResponseChannel);
        g.setExtractReplyPayload(false);
        g.setRequestPayloadTypeClass(IndexIntegrationRepresentation.class);
        g.setRequestMapping(requestMapping);
        g.setCrossOrigin(crossOrigin);
        g.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverters);
        g.setReplyTimeout(180000);
        return g;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Qualifier(value="responseHttpChannel")
    public MessageChannel responseHttpChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow tarefaHttpIndexIntegrationPartitionFlow(@Autowired TarefaIndexIntegrationHistory transformer) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("tarefaHttpIndexIntegrationChannel")
                .handle(transformer)
                .get();

    }
    
    private Message<?> logMessage(Message<?> m) {
        System.err.println(m.getPayload());
        return m;
    }

}
```

Any clue i will be glad.

Regards.

Comment: Fully not clear what you are asking. I think we need to start from the simple question: what is your business task? The we will try to lead you to the solution. Right now you show some pieces of code which don't connect to each other. You said "splitter" and "transformer", but you don't show that code. Anyway: please, read your question with fresh I and imagine that this text is not your own, but you try to understand it.

Comment: Hello, Indeed i managed to solve the problem of the aggregator on another way.  I have a request HTTP that will generate a list of tasks. I used a splitter on that list to generate a second list  , for each item of the first list the item will be analyzed and generate depending on the analysis a second list (subtasks). At the end i was planning to send a summary of the execution using an aggregator. But i realized that the time for finishing the tasks could be long. So i managed to send the response http on  another form.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Indeed worked very well, each task  a thread, and worked fine.. very fast. i tried to post the integration flow on the original post but exceeded the maximum size. the aggregator now works with a cache. i send a summary at the http response, this summary also goes to a cache divided on each item (the original task).at end of execution of each task or thread, the task stamps it's  execution as concluded on it's equivalent item stored on cache. now with websockets i will try to read the thread conclusion and the cache.

Comment: The complete Integration Flow is in the post. Thanks Artem

Comment: Ok. Glad you have fixed the problem some way! Unfortunately your business flow is too be for SO and for understanding by third person. You can add your one answer, but the future, please, consider to ask concrete small question. The big problem definitely can be divided to tiny tasks